# Apache Spark: updateStateByKey + multiple windows

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I need to "word-count" incoming stream, separate it into several windows and save independently.

```
JavaDStream<String> input = streamingContext.textFileStream("source_dir")
// split into (word,1) pairs (assumed more complex transformation in real life)
JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> wordCountStream = input
            .flatMapToPair(SPLIT_FUNCTION);
// have half-hour interval and one day
for(int minuteWindowSize : new Integer[]{30,1440})
{
   // assumed, that reduceFunc makes a+b, inverse: a-b
   JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> windowReduced = wordCountStream.reduceByKeyAndWindow(reduceFunc, inverseReduceFunc, Durations.minutes(minuteWindowSize), Durations.minutes(BATCH_PERIOD));
   windowReduced.foreachRDD(SAVE_FUNCTION);
}
```

In Spark web GUI I see two "huge" stages ::flatMapToPair (suppose, due to two windows), with same execution time and input.

What I expect, is a "small" ::flatMapToPair within data, arrived since last window computation, it's "sharing" within all windows and process small amount of data.

I feel, ::updateStateByKey should be used, saw separate examples on ::updateStateByKey and ::window, but don't understand, how to combine them.

How to implement word-count over several windows correctly?

Comment: A window of 1 day is quite large. Consider using alternative means to calculate daily aggregates, like 1 spark transformation on the minute or 1/2 hr aggregates that are already stored on some secondary storage.

Comment: @maasg, thanks for reply. And is that solution suitable: read aggregations from external storage, split them into time windows (counts and distincts per 30 minutes and 1440 minutes), and then each batch period (for example, 1 minute) transform each event into projection (count:1, count_distinct:1) and call ::updateStateByKey? I have about 120000 events/second and about 100000 projections, containing count and distinct.